# Q_OBJECT derived class, inheritance

Tags: qt, qobject

I am new in qt.
I have next inheritance:

```
class Poster : public QObject 
{
  Q_OBJECT
}

class SyncPoster: public Poster 
{
  Q_OBJECT

private slots:
  ... some functions

}

class TextPoster : public Poster
{

  Q_OBJECT

private slots:
   ... some functions

}
```

But assembling throws followed error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "vtable for SyncPoster",
>   referenced from:
>         SyncPoster::SyncPoster(Window*, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&, QString const&) in sync_poster.o   NOTE: a missing
>   vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has
>   no definition. ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

What does it mean, and what I do wrong? Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

One common case for this error is when you create a QObject derived class and you add or remove the Q_OBJECT without calling qmake before building.

The missing call to qmake will not trigger a re-parsing of the file and moc will not run if you just added Q_OBJECT.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar topic [Why am I getting "Undefined symbols ... typeinfo ... vtable" with a virtual and concrete class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306790/why-am-i-getting-undefined-symbols-typeinfo-vtable-with-a-virtual-and/23306827#23306827) :

> ...You seem to be confusing definition with declaration. What you have
>   in the base class is only declaration without definition, i.e.
>   implementation. You either need to make it pure virtual or implement
>   it even if it is just an empty {}...

Check the declaration and the definition of your constructor. Does your `SyncPoster` class **have a public constructor?** Does it have a definition? (have a body?)

```
SyncPoster::SyncPoster(/*...*/)
```

Check whether it has a body:

```
SyncPoster::SyncPoster(/*...*/) {}
                              //^^^  body
```

Comment: I have all the classes to have Q_OBJECT macro in header file. I have edited question

Comment: What I could figure out from it?

Comment: Check whether you have a declarations without definitions

Comment: I have checked all methods it seems ok. Actually I just rebuild some time my project and everything now is ok. It seems it was just IDE cache error.